# Bluetooth Connection Drops After Few Seconds

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, disconnect

I'm trying to connect my Arduino board with a JDY-30 module via Bluetooth to my Ubuntu 16.04. The connection is established, but drops after 5 seconds.
Does anyone else have issues with bluetooth connections? What do?

Comment: Found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/869951/301571), thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also problems with bluetooth connections on Ubuntu 17.10. I connected bluetooth speaker and it disconnects right away. I am also unable to turn bluetooth on and off.